# Different settings using GUI pop-up button (matlab)

Tags: matlab, user-interface, popupmenu

So I've been working on this GUI for a while, and recently finished a prototype where you could input resistance, inductance, and capacitance to get the quality factor, and the resonance frequency using equations. What I want to do now is to make a GUI that accepts different sets to find the missing values. ex:  given q-factor, resistance, and inductance. I've made a pop-up button that I want to switch depending on what the user has to input. I'm new to GUI programming, so I was wondering if making a giant If statement following the pop-up button is the simplest way. ex: if (RCL)... if(QLR)... of course this would make me type out tons of code for each setting, so I was wondering if there was an easier way. Thanks in advance.

In my gui I have 5 edit text boxes, a popup button, and a graph. what I want to happen is for the user to choose which setting they have depending on the inputs that they have, and for the remaining edit boxes to display the other values. so if they select the RCL setting, I want the program to take the RCL inputs, and calculate W and Q, then show them in the proper edit text boxes. I want this to be malleable though, so I have made several other settings such as CLW or QRL that the user can choose from, so they can get the missing variables. the graph will be a bode plot of a transfer function using the RCL values. the main problem is that for each setting, different forms of the same equation are used to calculate the missing values. Is there a way to call the function I need for a specific case and get the values everywhere I need them?

Comment: It's difficult to answer the "what's best" question without more concrete details.

Comment: Okay, I tried to make things clearer in the description. The edit part is the second paragraph. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not 100% following what you're looking for, but hopefully this gets you going in the right direction:

```
function testGUI
% Initialize dummy GUI
h.mainwindow = figure( ... % Main figure window
    'Units','pixels', ...
    'Position',[100 100 400 400], ...
    'MenuBar','none', ...
    'ToolBar','none', ...
    'Resize', 'off' ...
    );

h.var1box = uicontrol( ...
    'Parent', h.mainwindow, ...
    'Style', 'edit', ...
    'Units', 'Normalized', ...
    'Position', [0.4 0.5 0.2 0.1], ...
    'String', '0' ...
    );

h.var2box = uicontrol( ...
    'Parent', h.mainwindow, ...
    'Style', 'edit', ...
    'Units', 'Normalized', ...
    'Position', [0.4 0.3 0.2 0.1], ...
    'String', '0' ...
    );

h.var3box = uicontrol( ...
    'Parent', h.mainwindow, ...
    'Style', 'edit', ...
    'Units', 'Normalized', ...
    'Position', [0.4 0.1 0.2 0.1], ...
    'String', '', ...
    'Enable', 'off' ...
    );

h.var1label = uicontrol( ...
    'Parent', h.mainwindow, ...
    'Style', 'text', ...
    'Units', 'Normalized', ...
    'Position', [0.4 0.6 0.2 0.05], ...
    'String', 'Var1' ...
    );

h.var2label = uicontrol( ...
    'Parent', h.mainwindow, ...
    'Style', 'text', ...
    'Units', 'Normalized', ...
    'Position', [0.4 0.4 0.2 0.05], ...
    'String', 'Var2' ...
    );

h.var3label = uicontrol( ...
    'Parent', h.mainwindow, ...
    'Style', 'text', ...
    'Units', 'Normalized', ...
    'Position', [0.4 0.2 0.2 0.05], ...
    'String', 'Var3' ...
    );

h.dropdown = uicontrol( ...
    'Parent', h.mainwindow, ...
    'Style', 'popupmenu', ...
    'Units', 'Normalized', ...
    'Position', [0.3 0.7 0.4 0.05], ...
    'String', {'Var1'; 'Var2'; 'Var3'}, ...
    'Value', 3, ...
    'Callback', {@vartoggle, h} ...
    );

h.dropdownlabel = uicontrol( ...
    'Parent', h.mainwindow, ...
    'Style', 'text', ...
    'Units', 'Normalized', ...
    'Position', [0.3 0.75 0.4 0.05], ...
    'String', 'Variable to solve for?' ...
    );

h.calculatebutton = uicontrol( ...
    'Parent', h.mainwindow, ...
    'Style', 'pushbutton', ...
    'Units', 'Normalized', ...
    'Position', [0.72 0.7 0.2 0.05], ...
    'String', 'Calculate', ...
    'Callback', {@calcdata, h} ...
    );

end

function vartoggle(eventdata, ~, h)
% Execute on change in dropdown menu, enable/disable edit boxes
% appropriately

switch eventdata.Value
    case 1
        % Solve for variable 1
        h.var1box.Enable = 'off';
        h.var2box.Enable = 'on';
        h.var3box.Enable = 'on';
        h.var1box.String = '';
        h.var2box.String = '0';
        h.var3box.String = '0';
    case 2
        % Solve for variable 2
        h.var1box.Enable = 'on';
        h.var2box.Enable = 'off';
        h.var3box.Enable = 'on';
        h.var1box.String = '0';
        h.var2box.String = '';
        h.var3box.String = '0';
    case 3
        % Solve for variable 3
        h.var1box.Enable = 'on';
        h.var2box.Enable = 'on';
        h.var3box.Enable = 'off';
        h.var1box.String = '0';
        h.var2box.String = '0';
        h.var3box.String = '';

end
end

function calcdata(~, ~, h)
% Execute when calculate button is pressed, calculate missing value
% Asssumes Var1 + Var2 = Var 3 for this example
switch h.dropdown.Value
    case 1
        % Solve for variable 1
        B = str2double(h.var2box.String);
        C = str2double(h.var3box.String);
        A = C - B;

        h.var1box.String = A;
    case 2
        % Solve for variable 2
        A = str2double(h.var1box.String);
        C = str2double(h.var3box.String);
        B = C - A;

        h.var2box.String = B;
    case 3
        % Solve for variable 3
        A = str2double(h.var1box.String);
        B = str2double(h.var2box.String);
        C = A + B;

        h.var3box.String = C;
end
end
```

What this does is allow the user to specify the quantity to solve for and updates your ability to modify the edit boxes accordingly. Once you click the calculate button the missing value is calculated.

Comment: Thanks I got it. using your example, I just made a huge switch function and case commands to have the program switch settings depending on the user's choice.